# Can't turn off debugger in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, minitest

I wanted to debug a test (MiniTest) in my Rails app. Therefore I followed the instruction on the [Minitest-Debugger Github Page](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest-debugger). Here is the important snippet:

Add this to the top of your test file or helper:

```
require 'minitest/debugger' if ENV['DEBUG']
```

Then run your tests as normal but define DEBUG=1:

```
% DEBUG=1 rake test 
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.
```

Since then, all rails commands (like `rails server` or `bundle exec rake test`) I type into the console from my app directory try to start the debugger, which doesn't even work right but gives me some error messages from classes / parts outside my app.

```
% rails s
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

/Users/chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/binding_of_caller-0.7.2/lib/binding_of_caller/mri2.rb:25: `' (NilClass)
```

How can I reset my environment / Rails / Ruby so it runs normally. I tried of course:

```
% DEBUG=0 rails s
```

But that didn't change anything. I deleted everything I set up in order to debug.
What do I have to do to stop Rails from entering debug-mode?

Comment: have you tried export DEBUG=0 ?

Comment: I just tried it, same error.